# How to get statistics of secondary index (for example size on disk) in Cassandra 2.1.6?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cql

How to  get statistic secodary index (for example size index in HDD) in cassandra DB (version C* 2.1.6 )?

Comment: Can you clarify what  is required with example?

Comment: Agree.  Do you just want to see the definition in-schema?  Or do you want to see its size on-disk?

Comment: size on-disk. for example on GREENplum:
t=# \di+ tbl*
                                    List of relations
 Schema |         Name         | Type  |  Owner   |     Table      |  Size  | Description
--------+----------------------+-------+----------+----------------+--------+-------------
 public | tbl_pkey  | index | postgres | tbl | 156 MB |
 public | tbl_unpic | index | postgres | tbl | 46 MB  |
 public | tbl_x1    | index | postgres | tbl | 57 MB  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the output of `nodetool tablestats` (`cfstats` in earlier versions of Cassandra) specifically on the hidden index table of the table you're interested in.

To illustrate with an example, here's my table of community questions:

```
CREATE TABLE community.questions (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    author text,
    title text
)
```

If I create a secondary index on the `author` column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON community.questions (author)
```

a hidden table called `questions_author_idx` gets created in the background.

Here's an example output of the `cfstats` command on the hidden index table:

```
$ nodetool cfstats community.questions.questions_author_idx
Total number of tables: 66
----------------
Keyspace : community
    Read Count: 1
    Read Latency: 5.832 ms
    Write Count: 10
    Write Latency: 8.5428 ms
    Pending Flushes: 0
        Table (index): questions.questions_author_idxquestions.questions_author_idx
        SSTable count: 1
        Space used (live): 5148
        Space used (total): 5148
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 8
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.8454545454545455
        Number of partitions (estimate): 3
        ...
```

Note that the output of `nodetool` only relates to the node you're running on so you'll need to run it on all nodes. Cheers!

Comment: Not working
:~$ nodetool help tablestats
Unknown command tablestats
version C* is 2.1.6

Comment: analogue nodetool cfstats for example:  nodetool cfstats test.dict_test
Where in this index size on-disk??

Comment: Yep, `cfstats` got renamed to `tablestats` in newer versions. Run `cfstats` withOUT the table name and you'll need to scan the output for the hidden index table that you're looking for. Cheers!

Comment: Man, are you reding me? nodetool cfstats test.dict_test -- Where in this index size on-disk??

Comment: As I stated, just run `nodetool cfstats` withOUT the table name. Then you need to go through the output to locate the hidden index table for `dict_test`. Cheers!

Comment: Erick, show an example please. 
I don't quite understand where the index table has to do with it, I'm talking about the secondary index on the table - I need its size on disk (GB, MB, TB ...)

Comment: In Cassandra, the indexes aren't stored with the base table (table being indexed). When you index a table, a new hidden table gets created with the `_idx` suffix by default (unless you overrode the index name). That's the table you need to look at, not the base table. Cheers!

Comment: ok, now it's clear, thanks. Eric, is it possible to somehow get the file size (in centos for an example) in which the index is located?

Comment: I've updated my answer with examples. Cheers!